# how to set the image source from resource in wpf in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm

I want to set the image source to an image from resource. I have this xaml that works perfectly:

```
  <Image Source="/MyApplicationName;component/Resources/SplashScreen/InternetPlaceHolder.jpg" Height="577" Width="700" />
```

I want to change it in a way that the image is loaded in code . So I wrote this code:

```
   <Image Height="577" Width="700"  x:Name="Image"/>


    MyImage = new Image();
    BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
    logo.BeginInit();
    logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApplicationName;component/Resources/SplashScreen/InternetPlaceHolder.jpg");
    logo.EndInit();
    MyImage.Source = logo;
```

But it doesn't work.

I checked and the logo is not initialized from resource image. apparently something is wrong with the uri. I have checked it with documentations that I found and it seems that its format is correct.

My question: What is wrong with the URI?

Comment: Just a thought: have you tried using the overloaded `Uri` constructor that takes a `UriKind`? You could try specifying `UriKind.Absolute`. Not sure if it will make a difference, but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, tested but it doesn't work!

Comment: `logo.UriSource = new Uri("/MyApplicationName;component/Resources/SplashScreen/InternetPlaceHolder.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);` -- Try this...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must set image property `Build Action` to `Resource`. Then try following code:

```
ImagePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"Resources/SplashScreen","InternetPlaceHolder.jpg");
```

XAML:

```
<Image  Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="577" Width="700" />
```